# What is reason for adding processDialog in async task slow down it?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

This is an issue in proccess dialog in async task

I search a lot for finding the reason of **proccessDialog in Async task is SlowDown** speed of what you put in doInBackground.

Can anyone say why its occuring...

### Below is my code

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
         Asycdialog = new ProgressDialog(Server_connection.this);
         Asycdialog.setMessage("Checking Connection.......");

         Asycdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
         Asycdialog.show();


            field_res_partner = mf.fields_res_partner();


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OVersionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        sync_data_server.Search_read(Server_connection.this, "res.partner",
                field_res_partner);


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
         Asycdialog.dismiss();

        // Intent intent = new Intent(Server_connection.this,
        // SplashMenu.class);
        // startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Comment: How you can conclude that? show us proof.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }
```

to update your progress and :

```
publishProgress (Progress... values)
```

to send updating status to the progress

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...))

Comment: where actually i put "publishProgress (Progress... values)" in do in background after thee proccess completed or before the proceess??

Comment: Your code do all the stuff in one step, so I cannot know how to implement progress in this situation...
publishProgress usually used in work that have "progress" that done step by step, end every step u update the progress...